# Running into issues moving a Java Springboot application from Heroku to EC2/Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, ubuntu, heroku

I recently decided to migrate my Springboot application from Heroku to 2 EC2s (Ubuntu). One for the PostgresDB, and one for the application. I ate through some errors earlier in migrating the database, but now I have it working and can view its restored contents from PGadmin. Now when I run the application, it stops when adding in the templates. It does this using both mvn spring-boot:run and java -jar [name-of-application].jar. This below is the error message, and I included the last two logging statements that occur before this happens. I'm not really sure what to make of this as it doesn't point to any lines or classes I in my code/src, and from something I read it looks like this is coming from one of the maven plugins. If I get really desperate I would consider just rebuilding this and importing all of my classes once it is stable, but I'm hoping there is an easier way.

```
2021-06-14 23:40:16.980  INFO 6080 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-14 23:40:17.316  INFO 6080 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    
: Adding welcome page template: index
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:04 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-06-14T23:40:30Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven- 
plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project java-getting-started: Application finished 
with exit code: 137 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.0.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project 
java-getting-started: Application finished with exit code: 137
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build 
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit 
code: 137
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm 
(AbstractRunMojo.java:296)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:261)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:233)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo 
(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject 
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build 
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I fixed it:

I built it in my local to see if I could get a better look at what was going on. It built successfully and I was able to use it on my local. I went to the ide properties to see what version of JDK was running, and, to my surprise, it was running Java 11. I had thought that Heroku was running Spring-boot application in Java 8, but I was wrong. Switching to JDK 11 fixed the issue.